# Statistically significant when there are many different samples

Tags: statistical-significance

Let's say that I have a hundred medicines on the shelf and I want to check which one is the most effective for a certain disease. There were 10,000 patients. I divided them into 100 random groups and gave each group a different drug. The average outcome of one drug (no matter how we define the outcome, the main point is that it reflects efficacy) is  significance level of 1%. Would that indicate anything about the drug, or is it just static noise?

Comment: It means something, but the strength of such evidence is negligible. I would strongly recommend to repeat the procedure once more, but to include in the second round only the 10 most effective drugs from the first round.

Comment: @DanielDostal thank you. Why does it mean anything at all? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of statistical testing is to minimize both types of errors - to avoid false positives and false negatives. Let's see what is the probability that you will make one of these errors if we use your procedure.

I performed a little simulation (I repeated the procedure 10000 times on randomly generated numbers). Suppose that of the 100 drugs, 99 don't work (effest size = 0.0) and one has a moderate effect (Cohen's d = 0.5). If we follow your procedure, then the following holds:

- In approximately 99.6% of the cases, you will label the functioning drug as functioning.
- However, in approximately 63.1% of cases you will find at least one false significant result (you mark the non-functioning drug as functioning, alpha = 1%, onetailed).

For this reason, your results are not very reliable, since false positives are found in most cases among the identified drugs.

If we include a second step - identify the top 10 drugs and repeat the procedure (again group size = 100 for each drug).

- In approximately 99.98% of cases, the functioning drug will proceed to the second round.
- In approximately 99.5% of cases, the functioning drug will proceed to the second round and will again be identified as functioning (alpha = 1%, onetailed).
- In approximately 8.9% of cases, you will also identify another drug as a false positive.

If you find the probability of false positivity of around 9% unsatisfactory, you can tighten the conditions even further.